# Variable range in function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, range

I have problem with this code... How can I subtract variable global variable inside function and get it?

```
var liczba = 0
function create(data)
{
  liczba--
}

if(e.keyCode == 32)
{
  liczba++

  if(liczba<5)
  {
    create(liczba)
  }
}
```

When i try reduce variable `liczba` there is no change to its value

Please help me

Comment: Did you debug it to see if the statement was hit? Or place  log('decrease')  and  log('increase')  . Also your syntax is incorrect, you need ; at the end of every line, you should check your javascript errors, on chrome its Ctrl + Shift + j

Comment: If everything you posted is wrapped inside the event callback, then every time the enter key is pressed, `liczba` gets reset back to 0.

Comment: @Adacho is the below solution okay for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our assumption([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ukitul/1/edit))

It is best to get pressed key by **onkeypress**

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='return enterKeyPress(event);' />
```

And **CSS** could be

```
var liczba = 0;
function enterKeyPress(e){
  alert("In if.."+liczba);
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
       liczba = liczba + 1;
        alert("In if.."+liczba);
       if(liczba<5){
          create();
       }
    } else {
       create(); 
    }
}
function create(){
    alert("In function.."+liczba);
    liczba = liczba - 1;
}
```

Comment: @Adacho is this solution okay for you?

Comment: unfortunately no :/ I don't need it special example, but in general HOW to change global variable in local function and then get it :)